# Problem with ParametricNDSolveValue & WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I have a set of coupled differential equations, which I am trying to integrate parametrically. `Rast` is the parameter that is being varied. My code is as follows:

```
Constants

au = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"]; 
c = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"]; 
Qpr = 1; 
Lsun = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"]; 
Rsun = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"]; 
Msun = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"]; 
G = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], ("Meters"^2*"Newtons")/"Kilograms"^2]; 
year = QuantityMagnitudeUnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]; 
Myr = year*10^6; 
Gyr = year*10^9; 
Mwd = 0.6*Msun; 
Cst = 1.27; 
U = 1*10^17; 

Functions

L[t_] := (3.26*Lsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun)))/(0.1 + t/Myr)^1.18; 
Roche[dens_] := (0.65*Cst*Rsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun))^(1/3))/(dens/3000)^3^(-1); 
Papsis[t_] := a[t]*(1 - e[t]); 

Radiative Drag

RDdadtR = -((1/c^2)*((3*L[t]*Qpr*(2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(16*Pi*2000*Rast*a[t]*(1. - e[t]^2)^(3/2)))); 

RDdedtR = -((1/c^2)*((15*L[t]*e[t])/(32*Pi*Rast*2000*a[t]^2*Sqrt[1. - e[t]^2]))); 

RDsolR = ParametricNDSolveValue[{a'[t] == RDdadtR, e'[t] == RDdedtR, a[0] == 1*au, e[0] == 0.3, 
     WhenEvent[{Evaluate[Papsis[t] <= Roche[2000]]}, {tmax = t, "StopIntegration", Print["Target Accreted"]}]}, {a, e}, 
    {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, {Rast}]; 

RDasolR[Rast_, t_] := RDsolR[Rast][[1]][t]; 

RDesolR[Rast_, t_] := RDsolR[Rast][[2]][t]; 

Plot[Evaluate[Table[RDasolR[Rast, t], {Rast, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Semi-major Axis"}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[RDesolR[Rast, t], {Rast, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]], {t, 0, tmax}, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Eccentricity"}]
```

An error is raised, namely `Limiting value is not a machine sized real number.` I don't know where I'm going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you upload Raw InputForm without `In[]`?

Comment: Done! Hope that is more readable.

Comment: These errors are occurring because  (1)  `Gyr` has the unit `s` attached to it, and `tmax` is not defined until after `Plot` has been called.  In general, I recommend that you avoid using units in your computation.

Comment: I understand the problem about `Gyr` having units, but I'm unsure why `tmax` is defined after `Plot` has been called, given it should be defined as the time the integration is stopped. Is there a way of getting around this?

Comment: @testing09 there is a typo in your code in `a[0] == 6*AU` (you define `au` not `AU`). Also use non dimensional parameters by adding `//QuantityMagnitude`, for example `year = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"] //QuantityMagnitude`. Even with this correction there are no events with `a[t]*(1 - e[t]) <= Roche[2000]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have updated it and I think I have found the problem but don't know to implement the solution!. The problem is that the `WhenEvent` condition triggers and saves `t` to `tmax`. However, given there are multiple iterations, the `tmax` is not saved for each iteration. Hence, I'm thinking- do each of the `tmax` values need to be saved in some kind of list?

Comment: @testing09 You just made several typos with `QuanitityMagnitude@`. It should be  `QuantityMagnitude@`. Please, improve also   `year = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"];`. And can you check your function `Roche[dens_]`? Where did you take this function?

Comment: I have rectified the typos and changed the values, such that an event is triggered. The code above shows the error, where `tmax` is not correctly computed for each `Rast` parameter value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compute `a, e` first to show, that there are no such events we are looking for. This code is only working minimal example I been able to derive from the code above:

```
au = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"] // 
   QuantityMagnitude;
c = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"] // 
   QuantityMagnitude;
Qpr = 1;
Lsun = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"] // 
   QuantityMagnitude;
Rsun = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"] // 
   QuantityMagnitude;
Msun = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"] // 
   QuantityMagnitude;
G = UnitConvert[
    Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], ("Meters"^2*"Newtons")/
     "Kilograms"^2] // QuantityMagnitude;
year = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"] // 
   QuantityMagnitude;
Myr = year*10^6;
Gyr = year*10^9;
Mwd = 0.6*Msun;
Cst = 1.27;
U = 1*10^17;


(*Functions*)

L[t_] := (3.26*Lsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun)))/(0.1 + t/Myr)^1.18;
Roche[dens_] := (0.65*Cst*
     Rsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun))^(1/3))/(dens/3000)^3^(-1);
Papsis[t_] := a[t]*(1 - e[t]);


(*Radiative Drag*)

RDdadtR = -((1/
       c^2)*((3*L[t]*Qpr*(2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(16*Pi*2000*Rast*
         a[t]*(1. - e[t]^2)^(3/2))));

RDdedtR = -((1/
       c^2)*((15*L[t]*e[t])/(32*Pi*Rast*2000*a[t]^2*
         Sqrt[1. - e[t]^2])));

RDsolR = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][a][t] == RDdadtR, 
    Derivative[1][e][t] == RDdedtR, a[0] == 6*au, e[0] == 0.3}, {a[t],
     e[t]}, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, {Rast}];


RDasolR[Rast_] := RDsolR[Rast][[1]];

RDesolR[Rast_] := RDsolR[Rast][[2]];


{Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[RDsolR[Rast][[1]], {Rast, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]], {t, 0, 
   9*Gyr}, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Semi-major Axis"}, Frame -> True], 
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[RDsolR[Rast][[2]], {Rast, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]], {t, 0, 
   9*Gyr}, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Eccentricity"}, Frame -> True], 
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[RDsolR[Rast][[1]] (1 - RDsolR[Rast][[2]]) - 
     Roche[2000], {Rast, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001}]], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Eccentricity"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]
The last picture is the expression `Papsis[t] - Roche[2000]]` used for event detection. There is no time where  `Papsis[t] - Roche[2000]]<=0`, and therefore there are no such events.

**Update 1.** In a case of initial data `a[0] == 1*au, e[0] == 0.3` there are several events and we can detect and plot solution with events as follows (here we use `a[t]` in astronomical unit, and `t` in `Myr`)

```
au = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"] // 
    QuantityMagnitude // Rationalize;
c = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"] // 
    QuantityMagnitude // Rationalize;
Qpr = 1;
Lsun = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"] // 
    QuantityMagnitude // Rationalize;
Rsun = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"] // 
    QuantityMagnitude // Rationalize;
Msun = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"] // 
    QuantityMagnitude // Rationalize;
G = UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], ("Meters"^2*"Newtons")/
      "Kilograms"^2] // QuantityMagnitude // Rationalize;
year = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"] // 
    QuantityMagnitude // Rationalize;
Myr = year*10^6;
Gyr = year*10^9;
Mwd = 6/10*Msun;
Cst = 127/100;
U = 10^17;


(*Functions*)

L[t_] := (326/100*Lsun*(Mwd/(6/10*Msun)))/(1/10 + t)^(118/100);
Roche[dens_] := (65/100*Cst*
     Rsun*(Mwd/(6/10*Msun))^(1/3))/(dens/3000)^(-1/3);
Papsis[t_] := au a[t]*(1 - e[t]);

(*Radiative Drag*)

RDdadtR = -((1/
       c^2)*((3*L[t]*Qpr*(2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(16*Pi*2000*Rast*
         au a[t]*(1. - e[t]^2)^(3/2))));

RDdedtR = -((1/
       c^2)*((15*L[t]*e[t])/(32*Pi*Rast*2000*au^2 a[t]^2*
         Sqrt[1. - e[t]^2])));


Do[tmax[r] = 9 Gyr/Myr; 
 sol[r] = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][a][t] == (Myr/au) RDdadtR /. {Rast ->
          r}, Derivative[1][e][t] == Myr RDdedtR /. {Rast -> r}, 
      a[0] == 1, e[0] == 3/10, 
      WhenEvent[{Evaluate[Papsis[t] <= Roche[2000]]}, {tmax[r] = t, 
        "StopIntegration"}]}, {a[t], e[t]}, {t, 0, 9 Gyr/Myr}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 35][[1]] // Quiet; 
 tm[r] = If[tmax[r] < 9 Gyr/Myr, tmax[r], 9 Gyr/Myr]; 
 p[r] = {Plot[a[t] /. sol[r], {t, 0, tm[r]}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Time, Myr", "Semi-major Axis, AU"}, Frame -> True,
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"Rast = ", r 1.}], PlotRange -> All], 
   Plot[e[t] /. sol[r], {t, 0, tm[r]}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Time, Myr", "Eccentricity"}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"tmax = ", N[tm[r] 1., 3]}], 
    PlotRange -> All]};, {r, 10^-3, 1/100, 10^-3}]
Table[p[r], {r, 10^-3, 1/100, 10^-3}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: @AlexTrounev- thank you so much! One last question- you've removed the explicit time dependence from the expression. How do I now scale the x axis so it's in `Myr`?

Comment: @testing09 Actually in your code `Time` is in second, not in `Myr`. But if you wish to plot `Time, Gyr` or `Time, Myr` with `FrameLabel` option we can scaled `Plot` output.

Comment: @testing09 We can also use scaling `Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[RDsolR[Rast][[1]] /. t -> ts Myr, {Rast, 0.001, 0.01, 
    0.001}]], {ts, 0, 9*Gyr/Myr}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time, Myr", "Semi-major Axis"}, Frame -> True]`

Comment: I have a question about your solution- I understand that you have specified the stop condition in the Plot function. Does Mathematica automatically know that it should stop plotting when this expression goes to zero? The reason I ask is that I am trying to extract the time at which the integration is stopped. Sorry for so many questions but I'm trying to get better at Mathematica :) –

Comment: @testing09 integration is stopped a `t=9 Gyr` as it given in `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`.

Comment: Oh I understand- my original problem was trying to get the integration to stop when that condition was met. This way the plots don't break. If the condition is met, plots 1 and 2 don't work. e.g. for a value of a[0]=3 au, the first 2 plots break. Hence, why I was trying to use WhenEvent to stop the integration from proceeding once the condition is met

Comment: @testing09 Ah, sorry! See update 1 to my answer.